# what is the difference between running a script with "python" vs "python3" commands from the terminal in Conda virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, conda, virtual-environment

I am pretty new to virtual environments so please bear with me while I talk this out.

I am trying to run a script from the terminal in a conda virtual environment and I am wondering what the difference is between running a script using `python script.py` instead of `python3 script.py`

First, with the virtual environment active, `conda list` gives me

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
python                    3.8.12               h88f2d9e_0
pandas                    1.3.3            py38h5008ddb_0
```

However, running `python --version` results in `Python 3.8.12` while `python3 --version` results in `Python 3.8.0`, suggesting there are two different versions of python in the virtual environment(?)

Moreover, running `python` followed by `>>import pandas as pd` successfully imports pandas, while `python3` followed by `>>import pandas as pd` results in `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

Why are the commands `python` and `python3` referring to different versions of python if there is only one python installed in the virtual environment? Does `python3` refer to something outside of the virtual environment? Happy to provide any other terminal feedback if it's helpful.

Comment: that's depend in what interpreter you have associated to python and python3. for example I have configured the both the same

Comment: This really depends on what those commands resolve to.

Comment: "Why are the commands python and python3 referring to different versions of python if there is only one python installed in the virtual environment?" A virtual environment isn't a seperate thing, really. `python3` is resolvving to something in your `$PATH`

Comment: Run `which python` and `which python3` to see which python is used by which.